# Display number of cases in spss paneled chart

Tags: charts, spss

I am running a basic crosstab frequency analysis whose output gets displayed as three paneled charts. Everything in the output is ok, except I would like to know the number of cases in each of the panel, and have an "N=..." anywhere in the chart either as an annotation, or part of the label, or on top of the chart. Really, anywhere works as long as it's displayed.

I have not used SPSS syntax for a while, so I'm a little stumped. My hunch tells me that i should be able to create a new variable that has all the sums, and display that in the footnote of each of the panels, but I have no idea how to do that in SPSS.

Thank you.

```
GGRAPH 
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=RIncome COUNT()[name="COUNT"] YrOut_Group MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO 
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE. 
BEGIN GPL 
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset")) 
  DATA: RIncome=col(source(s), name("RIncome"), unit.category()) 
  DATA: COUNT=col(source(s), name("COUNT")) 
  DATA: YrOut_Group=col(source(s), name("YrOut_Group"), unit.category()) 
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Percent")) 
 GUIDE: text.title(label("Income Ranges by Years Out"))
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0)) 
  SCALE: cat(dim(3), include("4.00", "5.00", "10.00")) 
  ELEMENT: interval(position(summary.percent(RIncome*COUNT*YrOut_Group, base.all(acrossPanels()))), shape.interior(shape.square)) 
END GPL.
```

Answer (score 1):

First I will make some fake data that should generally look like yours to illustrate the options.

```
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP #i = 1 TO 1000.
  COMPUTE RIncome = TRUNC(RV.UNIFORM(1,4)).
  COMPUTE YrOut_Group = TRUNC(RV.UNIFORM(4,7)).
  END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
IF YrOut_Group = 6 YrOut_Group = 10.
```

Now, a simple option is to label each *bar* with the count by placing `label(COUNT)` in the `ELEMENT` statement. Not quite what you wanted but close.

```
GGRAPH 
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=RIncome COUNT()[name="COUNT"] YrOut_Group MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO 
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE. 
BEGIN GPL 
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset")) 
  DATA: RIncome=col(source(s), name("RIncome"), unit.category()) 
  DATA: COUNT=col(source(s), name("COUNT")) 
  DATA: YrOut_Group=col(source(s), name("YrOut_Group"), unit.category()) 
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Percent")) 
 GUIDE: text.title(label("Income Ranges by Years Out"))
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0)) 
  SCALE: cat(dim(3), include("4.00", "5.00", "10.00")) 
  ELEMENT: interval(position(summary.percent(RIncome*COUNT*YrOut_Group, base.all(acrossPanels()))), shape.interior(shape.square), label(COUNT)) 
END GPL.
```

[image]

One approach I have done in the past is to place the counts for each panel in the label for the panel. I do this by using `AGGREGATE` and then replacing `YrOut_Group` with the concatenation of that variable and the count within each group.

```
*Arbitrary label in each panel.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK YrOut_Group
  /TotalPanel = N.

STRING PanLab (A15).
COMPUTE PanLab = CONCAT(STRING(YrOut_Group,F2.0)," (N = ",STRING(TotalPanel,F3.0),")").
EXECUTE.

GGRAPH 
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=RIncome COUNT()[name="COUNT"] PanLab MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO 
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE. 
BEGIN GPL 
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset")) 
  DATA: RIncome=col(source(s), name("RIncome"), unit.category()) 
  DATA: COUNT=col(source(s), name("COUNT")) 
  DATA: PanLab=col(source(s), name("PanLab"), unit.category()) 
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Percent")) 
 GUIDE: text.title(label("Income Ranges by Years Out"))
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0)) 
  SCALE: cat(dim(3)) 
  ELEMENT: interval(position(summary.percent(RIncome*COUNT*PanLab, base.all(acrossPanels()))), shape.interior(shape.square)) 
END GPL.
```

[image]

Unfortunately when mixing the aggregate functions in the `VARIABLES` portion is is difficult to make summaries to place within the panel. So if you really want a label within the panel I would suggest to just summarize the data yourself and make your own labels.

```
*Placing a label in each panel.
*Is easier if you aggregate the data yourself.
DATASET DECLARE AggStats.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE = 'AggStats'
  /BREAK YrOut_Group RIncome
  /TotalRinc = N
  /TotalPanel = FIRST(TotalPanel).
DATASET ACTIVATE AggStats.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE = * MODE=ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK
  /TotalSamp = SUM(TotalRInc).
COMPUTE PercRinc = (TotalRinc/TotalSamp)*100.
MATCH FILES FILE = *
  /FIRST = Flag
  /BY YrOut_Group.
*Make label variable.
COMPUTE TotalPanel2 = TotalPanel.
IF Flag <> 1 TotalPanel2 = $SYSMIS.
FORMATS TotalPanel2 (F3.0).

GGRAPH 
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=RIncome YrOut_Group PercRinc TotalPanel2
   MISSING=VARIABLEWISE REPORTMISSING=NO 
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE. 
BEGIN GPL 
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset")) 
  DATA: RIncome=col(source(s), name("RIncome"), unit.category()) 
  DATA: PercRinc=col(source(s), name("PercRinc")) 
  DATA: TotalPanel2=col(source(s), name("TotalPanel2"), unit.category()) 
  DATA: YrOut_Group=col(source(s), name("YrOut_Group"), unit.category()) 
  TRANS: LabXRinc = eval("2.00")
  TRANS: LabYRinc = eval(13.5)
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Percent")) 
  GUIDE: text.title(label("Income Ranges by Years Out"))
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0)) 
  SCALE: cat(dim(3), include("4.00", "5.00", "10.00")) 
  ELEMENT: interval(position(RIncome*PercRinc*YrOut_Group), shape.interior(shape.square)) 
  ELEMENT: point(position(LabXRinc*LabYRinc*YrOut_Group), label(TotalPanel2))
END GPL.
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm going to try it out, and see what happens.Thank you!

Comment: How can I specify where the values should appear at the top? ANd is there a way to have them say something other than just the number? Something like N=X?

Comment: @DrGeek - which chart are you referring to? The second chart if you put `GUIDE: axis(dim(3), opposite())` it will place the labels for the panels above the panel. The third chart you manually specify where the place the points and the labels in the `TRANS` statements.

Comment: I got the chart to do what I want it to do, except now I lost my labels on the axis. :(

Answer (score 0):

@andy-w

I got the chart to do what I want it to do, except now I lost my labels on the axis.

Followed exactly the code above with some minor modifications. Here is the new code.

```
DATASET DECLARE AggStats.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE = 'AggStats'
  /BREAK RHEDS_YrOut_Group RIncome
  /TotalRinc = N
  /TotalPanel = FIRST(TotalPanel).
DATASET ACTIVATE AggStats.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE = * MODE=ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK
  /TotalSamp = SUM(TotalRInc).
COMPUTE PercRinc = (TotalRinc/TotalSamp)*100.
MATCH FILES FILE = *
  /FIRST = Flag
  /BY RHEDS_YrOut_Group.
*Make label variable.
COMPUTE TotalPanel2 = TotalPanel.
IF Flag <> 1 TotalPanel2 = $SYSMIS.
FORMATS TotalPanel2 (F3.0).

GGRAPH 
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=RIncome PercRinc RHEDS_YrOut_Group MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO 
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE. 
BEGIN GPL 
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset")) 
  DATA: RIncome=col(source(s), name("RIncome"), unit.category()) 
  DATA: PercRinc=col(source(s), name("PercRinc")) 
 DATA: TotalPanel2=col(source(s), name("TotalPanel2"), unit.category()) 
  DATA: RHEDS_YrOut_Group=col(source(s), name("RHEDS_YrOut_Group"), unit.category()) 
  TRANS: LabXRinc = eval("5") 
  TRANS: LabYRinc = eval(20) 
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Percent")) 
  GUIDE: axis(dim(3), label("HEDS Years out"), opposite()) 
 GUIDE: axis(scale(RIncome)) 
   GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color), null()) 
    SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0)) 
  SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color), include("4", "5", "10"), map(("4", color.lightgreen), ("5", color.MediumSpringGreen), ("10", color.green))) 
 TRANS: RIncome_TRANS = collapse(category(RIncome), minimumPercent(0.5), sumVariable(COUNT), otherValue("Other")) 
  ELEMENT: interval(position(RIncome*PercRinc*RHEDS_YrOut_Group), shape.interior(shape.square), color(RHEDS_YrOut_Group)) 
   ELEMENT: point(position(LabXRinc*LabYRinc*RHEDS_YrOut_Group), label(TotalPanel2), color(RHEDS_YrOut_Group)) 
END GPL.
```

I can't post the output here, since I don't have 10 points yet. But from the code you can tell that I'm also still trying to include the N= at the top.